# how to use src-address in mikrotik script 'find'

Tags: mikrotik, routeros

```
:foreach i in=[/ip fi man find chain=forward ] do={
    :put [/ip fi man get value-name=src-address $i]
}
```

I get:

```
192.168.1.99
192.168.1.100
192.168.1.101
192.168.1.102
```

```
:foreach i in=[/ip fi man find chain=forward src-address=192.168.1.100 ] do={
    :put [/ip fi man get value-name=src-address $i]
}
```

I get nothing

Question: how to use src-address in 'find' ?

The hint in mikrotik script is

```
SrcAddress ::= [!]Range
  Range ::= A.B.C.D[-A.B.C.D |0..32 |/A.B.C.D ]    (IP address range)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
:foreach i in=[/ip fi man find chain=forward src-address="192.168.1.100" ] do={:put [/ip fi man get value-name=src-address $i] }
```

Use quote for src-address and dst-address